# What kind of sorting do we have in std::map or std::set?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

If we insert random integers in std::set, and read the set, we get ordered sequence. Basically, we have implicit sorting. However, what kind of sorting algorithm do we have here? Is it heapsort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least normally, it's a tree sort. That is, the items are inserted into a balanced binary search tree (usually a red-black tree), and that tree is traversed in order.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard doesn't enforce any kind of sorting algorithm for `std::set` or `std::map`. So their implementations might differ among different platforms.

With that said, they are commonly implemented as a red-black tree, which is  a self-balancing binary search tree. They don't sort their contents, they maintain the order of their contents as new items are inserted. Inserting a single item to them is usually O(logn).

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` and `std::map` are usually implemented using self-balancing binary search trees, usually red-black trees because they tend to be the fastest in practice. For detailed information about these data structures, you might want to consult a textbook such as *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen *et al.* or *Algorithms* by Sedgewick.